# Delphi 7 crashes when running programs on Windows 7

Tags: delphi, windows-7, delphi-7

I have just got a new machine running Windows 7.  I have installed Delphi7 Enterprise (Build 4.453) with no problems.  However when I try to run **any** program from the IDE, Delphi just crashes, with no error message at all.  Even running the default project1 it crashes.  Any ideas?

Here is some more information.

Delphi was installed by running the install.exe as Administrator and installing to C:\Borland\Delphi7 (avoiding Program Files folder).

The delphi32.exe is run as Adminstrator.

I have set the security of users for the c:\Borland folder to full control.

I have tried setting UAC to disabled and this makes no difference.

Windows 7 is 32-bit version.

Comment: I've no idea why this would happen. I've never known such a problem. I would say though that you can run Delphi 7 quite happily installed under C:\Program Files and with UAC enabled.

Comment: I wouldn't avoid the "Program Files" folder. That might actually be your problem. Install in the Program Files folder as usual, and - if necessary - run delphi32.exe as administrator, and possibly in Windows XP compatibility mode. There should be no problems at all.

Comment: Did you applied the Update Pack 1.1? It could be a debugger issue, anyway. I would back off the changes you made to folder security, they are useless and just made your system less secure, for example virus like W32/Induc-A would have an easy life on your system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just wanted to thanks people for their help and let you know that the problem has been fixed.

I'm embarrassed to say that the problem was not caused by Windows7 or Delphi7 but by BitDefender trying to protect me.  Once a setting had been changed in BitDefender it worked;  shame it didn't think to tell me when it was closing Delphi.

Comment: Good to hear. If I were you I would now reinstall to undo all the security changes you made last time round. It's wise to get a nice clean install in place.

Comment: Thanks, zendar I will do.  Its says I can accept my own answer in 4 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing with UAC off, it helped me with even earlier version of Delphi (you can return UAC back after that)

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't happen.  I'd say it's definitely a bad install, my guess is a corrupt phyiscal disk.  Time to run disk check and likely reformat/reinstall the operating system.

Comment: seems a bit strong to me. Ought to be possible to debug the crash with SysInternals tools.

Comment: -1: This is too drastic. I actually guess that Darian misread the question. ("However when I try to run any program in Windows, it crashes...")

Comment: It's not any program start problem, it's only Delphi IDE compiled application start problem. Correct quoting is this: "However when I try to run any program from the IDE, Delphi just crashes".